# Conky won't display an image

Tags: linux, conky

I found recently that Conky can display images, so wanted to try this.

The line in my conky file is as follows:

```
${image /home/scott/Desktop/soho/soho-eit284.jpg}
```

I've double-checked the path is correct and is a valid JPG. Instead of the literal path, I also tried ~/Desktop... and $HOME/Desktop.. as I've seen posts on here that show that as working code.

Any way I try, I simply get this on-screen:

```
${image}
```

instead of the image.
Conky --version reports:

```
conky 1.10.6 compiled Thu Sep 14 05:41:24 UTC 2017 for Linux 4.4.0-93-generic x86_64
```

I'm using Xubuntu 17.10 Kernel 4.13.11-041311-generic

On some posts I've read, people mention compiling their own Conky to add a specific feature, is that is what is required? If so, any tutorial or step-by-step instructions on how to do that?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: Nearly 2 weeks and 25 views, no replies. Do I win a prize if no one can answer? :-) I'm new here, have I explained what the problem is properly and shown what I've done so far to figure out what's wrong? Is my question not even worth one up-vote?

I do get a prize: Stackoverflow Tumbleweed award! Well, that's something I guess.

<del>**UPDATE2**: Not a solution, but a workaround. Wrote my own image displayer using Python+PyQt to run along-side Conky :-)</del>
https://pastebin.com/mxGat789

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same issue; installing the `conky-all` package got it working.

(I know this is an old question; just posting the fix since it's the first search result.)

Comment: YES! thank you so much. Tried to up-vote your answer, but not enough reputation :-(
sudo killall conky
sudo apt install conky-all
(I had conky-std installed)